# How to handle own, unanswered question with an unrelated answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, vote-to-delete

I have question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915778/mmap-dev-fb0-fails-with-invalid-argument) where I found the solution by myself. It's nothing related to the tags or topic but a simple programming bug (mmapsize becomes larger than screen size for the given values if you are interested). Now I see 5 options how to proceed:

1. leave the question as is - No gain for anyone.
2. delete the question - would be okay with me but deleting questions isn't really in the sense of SO
3. answering my question with the correct answer - no one will find it with those specific tags
4. rework my question to fit the answer - risking duplicates and the comments aren't right to.
5. deleting it, create a new one and answer it - feeling a bit stupid because of the silly mistake.

What is the SO way to handle this?

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). Your question is the top hit in a search for `mmap /dev/fb0`.

Answer (score 3):

- **leave the question as is - No gain for anyone.**

  As you said, "No gain for anyone", so we can rule this one out
- **delete the question - would be okay with me but deleting questions isn't really in the sense of SO**

  If you don't see this helping anyone else then deleting would be in the best interest of SO
- **answering my question with the correct answer - no one will find it with those specific tags**

  This seems fitting. Change the tags to be appropriate and answer if you believe the question can help others with the appropriate tags
- **rework my question to fit the answer - risking duplicates and the comments aren't right to.**

  This one doesn't quite make sense. There are no answers and if you mean the answer that fixed your problem then it still seems awkward. If this is the case then I would delete the question, if it were me
- **deleting it, create a new one and answer it - feeling a bit stupid because of the silly mistake.**

  If you asked the wrong question and the new q/a can be helpful to others then this would probably be best so that the comments aren't confusing

Comment: Option #4 kind of goes with #3.  He means rework the question to describe his real problem and also answer it, rather than providing the answer to his problem without fixing the question to actually describe his problem.

Comment: @Servy I see, I was a bit confused. However, in option 3 he mentions the tags which is why I thought that would be a good option while changing the tags to be appropriate (if possible). And boy did my formatting suck on this one!

Answer (score 1):

1. Is pretty obviously out.  It leaves an artifact for people to find, but has no answer.  So either nobody finds it, and nobody is helped, or people find it and get no answer.  There is no good case here.
2. If the question isn't adding any value as it stands, deleting it is an entirely valid option.  We have a problem deleting *valuable* content, not deleting unhelpful content.
3. As you've said, if nobody can find it, then it's not helpful.
4. As to the comments being off, that's not a problem.  Flag the comments as obsolete if it bothers you.

   If there is a duplicate, then either your question improves the visibility/searchability of that question, in which case, vote to close it as a duplicate, or it doesn't improve the visibility, in which case, it can just be deleted.
5. While it sounds like you're making a radical enough change that this would be *allowed*, I don't really see any major advantages here over the previous point, so while this isn't *wrong*, I don't see it as a huge improvement either.