# Should I delete my question if issue is unrelated to original question?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, moderation

I asked this question earlier today:

[Access 2010 vba TempVars creation compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761867/access-2010-vba-tempvars-creation-compile-error/24764902#24764902)

I just arrived home and tested the same syntax with my home copy of Access 2010 and the syntax works the way it is supposed to.

As the issue I'm having seems to be related to the version or install of access that I have at work, should I delete this question since the issue isn't related to a "programmer's" bug but more of a software bug with my work copy of Access?

Should I edit my question to reflect that I now know the issue is with the software and try to get an answer for that issue?

Should I leave it as is, make a comment about my findings tonight and flag it for a more experienced stackoverflow user to decide?

Just wondering what the proper etiquette on stackoverflow is for a situation like this.

Also, it might be worth nothing that I use Access at work, but it is not my profession, it's something I do for them on the side, in case anyone assumes I know more about Access than I actually do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle own, unanswered question with an unrelated answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256538/how-to-handle-own-unanswered-question-with-an-unrelated-answer)

Comment: @random, I did have a look at that one, it seems that the user in that question found the cause of their issue, I've found that my issue isn't my code, but I still haven't found why access is causing me grief, thus my reasoning for asking this question here.

Comment: It'd be like if you answered that it was solved by something no one could have guessed. Your cause is unhinged from the problem scape, which is similar to when the answer is in another room.

Comment: @random, Your point is exactly what I'm struggling with, do I delete the question? Do I edit it to reflect the true issue I'm having in case someone else has this issue? I just want to know what the community thinks the right thing to do is.

Comment: If an edit steers the question back on track and away from the path you may have suggested in the original (to the unrelated issue you thought it was), make the edit

Comment: @random, That makes sense to me as well. I'll have a look at the versions and such when I'm at work next so that I can properly edit the question.

Comment: You might want to put a disclaimer at the top your question right now so people can expect a change at some point and won't answer the "wrong" question.

Comment: @user3580294, Good idea, I went ahead and did that.

Comment: Edited it to make it more prominent, but otherwise seems fine with me.

Comment: I saw that, thank you, it looks a lot better now.

Comment: Alright, I've updated my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761867/access-2010-vba-tempvars-creation-compile-error with my findings, it seems this is an Access issue 100%, so what now, does the question get moved?