# Should I delete (my own) unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've been around for 2 years but not very active until lately. I asked a few questions, some of which got answered some didn't.

Now my question is should I delete those questions that didn't get any answers at all (for whatever reason that may be)?

Is it better to just delete them because I feel like they ain't going help anyone?

Partly because they were kind off "stupid" questions but they got no answers either so basically they're irrelevant.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yup, I see now how the ban works. Thank You. I asked because I was reading code magic's answer to  this [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256538/how-to-handle-own-unanswered-question-with-an-unrelated-answer?rq=1) . It says something in the line of: if you don't see (the questions) helping anyone else then deleting would be in best interest of SO.

Comment: [Here you say](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27462566/211160) *"Thank You very much. I've got this problem sorted out but have another one. If you could have a look it'd be nice. :)"*  If you've sorted it out, the proper thing to do is self-answer and accept it.  Write the answer as if someone else had asked the question.  That's not only acceptable, it's encouraged.  And--even better (as I've noticed from self-answering) is that sometimes people come along and go "you overlooked this aspect in your solution"...so it's not just helping others, it may help you.

Comment: HostileFork Well, actually I thought of answering it myself but I didn't want to look ungrateful folibis and  @BaCaRoZzO (because speaking frankly he/she was the only one that cared about my questions and tried to help). Besides if someone is facing the same problem they'll find the answer in the comments. (by folibis and bacarozo).

Comment: @hekri If people answer in comments, it's not slighting them to use their info to write up a formal answer. They were not feeling up to crafting a full answer and often, if someone is not very interested in reputation, they'd rather you connect the dots. Credit them in the answer and that's enough. The issue you raise is *"what is the cost of an unanswered question to the system"*...imagine a world where all comments were deleted or expired after an amount of time (a concept that has been suggested). One shouldn't have to dig through comments for answers. I forgive myself here as it's meta.

Comment: My second highest voted question has been unanswered for 5 years. However I still accumulate votes on it, so it must still be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the grand scheme of things it probably doesn't make a lot of difference. Having said that, I would certainly leave any questions (answered or not) that you think might be at all useful to others. It's certainly possible that someone else will find it, find the answer somewhere else and then post an answer to help people in the future even though the question is old. However, if you look at the questions and you honestly think that they won't be of use to anyone, then it's probably better to delete them. I'd personally try to err on the side of not deleting though, since it's pretty hard to reliably predict what will be useful to other people.

Answer (score 26):

I would not delete them at this point except if they were to be unsalvageably inappropriate for the site.

You have only 5 (visible) questions and 4 answers so far. Be aware of this passage from the [FAQ entry on question bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

> It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of
>   your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently
>   they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from
>   users who read them, edit them, or respond to them. Therefore deleted
>   posts have an effect on the filter, among many other factors.

Comment: yep a 33% deletion rate might alredy get someone banned, easily reachable with a low number of posts

Answer (score 12):

I think not. A question that is not answered in two years, means something. It contains information, that can be useful.
If I asked two years ago, "How can I cross compile go code on iOS" and it got number of upvotes and there is no answer for it, it means "hey this is something that people care about and there is no solution for someone needs to do something about it"

Of course there are cases where I asked a question and realized it was a silly mistake or misunderstanding on my part THAT IS VERY UNLIKELY to happen to anyone else, in such cases I think deleting your own question is not only ok, but is recommended.

Still there are many silly mistakes or misunderstandings that are bound to happen to others as well, and while embarrassing I will mostly keep the question for others to find and save time and frustration.

Comment: My questions are not that old. They were asked 2 weeks ago atmost. Like I said up high, I don't think they will be of any use to someone because they're mostly related to the lack of  information - learning resources on that particular subject (QML/C++ integration). It's not like these questions are hard to answer (actually it's the opposite) or something but they just weren't answered for whatever reason. Maybe people thought they're just to dumb and not worth the time...idk.

Comment: I think if you, yourself think the question is not useful for anyone. Then I am more leaned toward deleting it. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you find the solution to those problems, it will be nice for newcomers you self answer that questions, maybe other people have the same issues like you