# Why and how do neglected questions get deleted? Should they be?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

Long ago I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20201761/699305) that didn't get any reactions-- it earned me a "tumbleweed" badge :-). Today I happened to notice that it had been "deleted by Community". It didn't get any downvotes, it wasn't a duplicate, off-topic, or a terrible question; it just wasn't seen by anyone who could answer it. So which policy led to its deletion?

I didn't find anything specifically on neglected questions on meta. The question certainly doesn't meet any of the criteria for deletion listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58842/when-should-i-vote-to-delete/59054#59054). On the contrary, there are any number of discussions that [suggest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280888/699305) that good unanswered questions should be kept around.

I'd prefer to leave this question in place in hopes that it will get an answer some day, but I don't need to be consoled or anything. Mainly I'm curious.

**Edit:** Thanks to @eldarerathis, we have the algorithm that led to its deletion:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244042. "If the question is more than 365 days old, and ... has a score of 0, ... it will be automatically deleted." Well, the wisdom of the site's owners has spoken.

<strike>But I notice it takes 8 votes to reopen it; isn't that a little excessive? For a question with no downvotes?</strike> (No it doesn't, I misinterpreted the meaning of "7 votes remaining" in the pop-up. It's 3 votes, thanks @Louis.)

Comment: The full criteria are outlined on [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/150283). Not sure if there's a list on this meta anywhere (yet).

Comment: Thanks! That's it: "If the question is more than 365 days old, and ... has a score of 0, ..."

Comment: 8 votes to reopen??? Where do you get that number? For one thing your question is not closed. And unless I'm misremembering something it should take only 3 votes to undelete it.

Comment: related (sort of "inverted duplicate"): [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt)

Comment: You could also just repost it. :)

Comment: @Louis, That's three undelete votes by 10k users, which an old, forgotten, and deleted question is unlikely to ever get (unless it experiences the meta effect and gets lots of people seeing it, such as the one linked in the question here).

Comment: So, it's been a **year** and there are no answers and no up-votes... I think the phrase I'm looking for is "take a hint" :) I earned a Tumbleweed on the one question I've asked in five years. I put a bounty on it and what do you know? I got an answer. Not an answer that actually fixed my problem, but it got some attention... and an up-vote.

Comment: @Louis, I got the number when I tested the waters by clicking on the question's "undelete" link. Try it.

Comment: @Mike, what hint should I take? I can't offer a bounty on a deleted question. Yes, I could ask it again, but that would be bypassing an explicit SO clean-up policy which strikes me as silly (or worse).

Comment: @alexis The number I see if I click on "undelete" (there's no "reopen" link because the question is *not* closed) is the number of undelete votes *I have remaining* today. I don't see any other numbers that correspond to a figure of 8.

Comment: @Jonas, I have over 12k points but I see "7 votes remaining" in the pop-up.

Comment: @Louis, I see; I misinterpreted the meaning of "remaining" in this context. Thanks!

Comment: @alexis, This means that _you_ still have 7 undelete votes left, which means that you can vote to undelete 7 further questions today. See the [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), under the "What happens when a post is deleted",  for the details.

Comment: The hint is that your question is not "useful", as no one has clicked the button which indicates that (or an equal number of people found the negative as found the positive). My point with the bounty is that you could have added a bounty to draw more attention to it. Coming here after a year of letting the question wallow in obscurity complaining that it takes many votes to undelete it sounded to me like an XY problem. Namely, that your problem is an uninteresting question, not that you need a lot of votes to undelete it.

Comment: Mike, the problem is that it is a niche question. It's not a popularity contest (unless you're in it for the internet points).

Comment: Mike, I think you're saying that if I have a problem that stackoverflow can't help me solve, I should try having a different problem? No thanks.

Comment: All I'm saying is that if you have a question, which has not seen any activity in a year, it seems reasonable, to me, for the system to say, "this is going nowhere, it should be deleted" and for the onus to be on you to provide a good reason for the question to be undeleted. It's not a popularity contest, and I'm certainly not suggesting you have a different problem. You seem to have sufficient "internet points" to add a bounty to the question to keep it alive in the niche for an extended period of time before you lose any of the privileges you've accrued.