# Should I delete my question if it turns out it's very specific to my case?

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252415/c-cli-which-pointer-to-use

I have since found the true reason, which is very specific to my case.

Should I delete my question because it's so specific ? Should I flag it for close vote myself? Should I leave it alone and mark my answer as accepted ?

I have seen this [How to handle own, unanswered question with an unrelated answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256538/how-to-handle-own-unanswered-question-with-an-unrelated-answer) but I'm still not sure of the correct course of action.

I see that *"repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking"*. How does it work ?

Comment: It falls in the "I had a typo" category.  If you in fact *had* posted your native code then somebody could have said "you have a typo".  As-is, it is very unlikely to be useful to anybody else.

Comment: Ok, so do I delete my question or vote to close it ?

Comment: Do you really need help from another 7 SO users to remove the question?   That's not going to happen, this is something you can take care of all by yourself.