# I got question blocked and most of my questions already have answers, but are rarely visited: how to proceed?

Tags: support, post-ban, bad-questions

TL;DR: I got banned, but my questions are already answered. I deleted questions I considered non-constructive (either because they were brain farts or because I couldn't reproduce the problem any more). To be unbanned, it is suggested to review one's questions, but there is not much I can do about mine. What can I do to get back on track?

---

I've restarted using this profile about six months ago. My idea was to build a strong Stack Overflow profile and actually getting involved in the open source / open knowledge community so my main objective was to have a `answered/asked ratio > 1` and a `questions asked/questions with an answer ratio > 1`, which involved answering others and answering my own questions if I found an answer. Since some questions are very specific, I "shared the knowledge", but this doesn't bring lots of votes.

I used to delete [terrible answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681419/manually-read-json-values/37681616#37681616)  and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130568/optional-gives-me-object-instead-of-the-type-i-assigned-to-it) (this question should be deleted, IMO, but it would influence my banned score for the worst still), [referring to @HansPassant's sarcastic answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288978/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-turns-out-its-very-specific-to-my-case), which I interpreted as *"do you actually need someone to tell you?"*. Plus, I made sure the questions were actually dead.

I've read all I could in the past two hours regarding unbanning, but there is not much, as far as I see, I can **NOT** review about the questions I have posted. What is the right approach in this case?

Comment: some questions just can't be fixed. however, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130568/optional-gives-me-object-instead-of-the-type-i-assigned-to-it) would benefit from you including the code you found to be prolematic, thus resulting in a problem that is reproducable. That doesn't mean you'll get upvotes to reduce the damage though. Might even result in the opposite due to it being bumped.

Comment: The ban at most will last 6 months. After that, you can try again. Note that it only gives you one more question, if that question isn't good quality you'll then have to wait 6 more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the right approach in this case?

---

> as far as I see, I can review about the questions I have posted.

That's it. Review, edit and improve them. Hope to get upvotes on the edited questions (editing bumps them to the front page).

Comment: I wrongly wrote "can" instead of "can't", which contradicts the title and the TLDR. I am passing over them anyway, but I actually don't know what could influence the ban-score

Comment: Why can you *not* review them? Are they so perfect they can't be improved at all?

Comment: Heh, I wish. No, of course they can and I guess I will in the meanwhile. Although: would you improve a question which is already readable and already has an answer?

Comment: @Vale - why not? If I notice issues with it that I can fix. And in your case, you have a good incentive to improve them - to get out of a ban.

Comment: Just please don't make edits that don't result in improvement but end up bumping your posts @Vale to the front page. There's the risk of the meta effect having the opposite effect to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonClements I'll try to do something about them. From an answer on the topic:  "So if many of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted, closed, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they did not meet the required quality". I've been looking at some of my questions and I feel I'm starting a journey to rephrase or "write blog posts" about the problems I encountered (for the majority of the questions, some actually need review).